# batch to vbs for loop translation

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have directory with executable files like

```
tool-7.0.20.exe
tool-7.0.23.exe
tool-7.0.24.exe
tool-7.0.25.exe
tool-7.0.26.exe
```

and I'm using a for loop in a batch file to get the latest version in a variable and run it
I need to convert this for loop to a vbs script

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /ON /B %~dps0tool*.exe') do set latest=%%a
```

then run the latest file variable with objShell.Exec or objShell.Run

Thanks

Comment: Is there a question in here? Or is this a script-for-me request?

Comment: What do you need VBScript for? You seem to have a `for` command that works and you plan to run an executable, so why not simply stay with the batch file?

Comment: Please don't just randomly add tags because they contain familiar words or phrases. I removed both the Powershell and DOS tags, because your question has nothing to do with either of those things. (Windows batch files do not run on DOS and haven't for a decade.)

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers, Ken White, Cindy Meister, greg-449, Tushar, You can read @omegastripes Answer to understand what I'm asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `Shell.Application` ActiveX:

```
Option Explicit

Const SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS = &H40
Const SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN = &H80
Dim strCurDir, strPath, objWshShell

strCurDir = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\"))
With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(strCurDir).Items
    .Filter SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS + SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN, "tool-*.exe"
    strPath = .Item(.Count - 1).Path
End With
WScript.Echo strPath
Set objWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objWshShell.Run strPath
```

Or by retrieving files with `Scripting.FileSystemObject` and filtering them with `VBScript.RegExp`:

```
Option Explicit

Dim strFiles, objMatches, strPath, objWshShell

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    With .GetFolder(.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName))
        strFiles = ""
        For Each strPath In .Files
            strFiles = strFiles & strPath & vbCrLf
        Next
    End With
End With
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "^.+?\\tool-.*?\.exe$"
    Set objMatches = .Execute(strFiles)
    strPath = objMatches(objMatches.Count - 1).Value
End With
WScript.Echo strPath
Set objWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objWshShell.Run strPath
```

Or even running your cmd code (cmd instructions were slightly modified to be executed in one liner command line mode):

```
Option Explicit

Dim objWshShell, strCurDir, strCmd, strRes

Set objWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCurDir = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\"))
strCmd = "%comspec% /v /c (for /f %a in ('dir /ON /B /S " & strCurDir & "tool-*.exe') do @set latest=%a)&echo !latest!"
strRes = objWshShell.Exec(strCmd).StdOut.ReadAll()
strRes = Replace(strRes, vbCrLf, "")
WScript.Echo strRes
objWshShell.Run strRes
```

If you want to get rid of the flashing console window, the above code may be modified as follows to launch second instance of the script in hidden mode, and execute cmd instructions within it:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objWshShell, strCurDir, strCmd, strRes, objWnd, objParent, strSignature

Set objWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("signature") Then WshShellExecCmd
strCurDir = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\"))
strCmd = "%comspec% /v /c (for /f %a in ('dir /ON /B /S " & strCurDir & "tool-*.exe') do @set latest=%a)&echo !latest!"
RunCScriptHidden
strRes = Replace(strRes, vbCrLf, "")
WScript.Echo strRes
objWshShell.Run strRes

Sub RunCScriptHidden()
    strSignature = Left(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").Guid, 38)
    GetObject("new:{C08AFD90-F2A1-11D1-8455-00A0C91F3880}").putProperty strSignature, Me
    objWshShell.Run ("""" & Replace(LCase(WScript.FullName), "wscript", "cscript") & """ //nologo """ & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ ""/signature:" & strSignature & """"), 0, True
End Sub

Sub WshShellExecCmd()
    For Each objWnd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        If IsObject(objWnd.getProperty(WScript.Arguments.Named("signature"))) Then Exit For
    Next
    Set objParent = objWnd.getProperty(WScript.Arguments.Named("signature"))
    objWnd.Quit
    objParent.strRes = objWshShell.Exec(objParent.strCmd).StdOut.ReadAll()
    WScript.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, VBScript.RegExp method worked best for me